# How can I create an object or array of array data in JS with key named elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array called `values`. At present, I'm appending new data to this array as such:

```
values.push(guests);
```

The result of my array is something like this:

```
["123456789", "Joe", "Bloggs", "Test Corp", "fiji", true, "guest, guest 2, guest 3", true]
```

I have now realised that in its present state this data is useless to me as I cannot tell what each element is. In my example above, the first long number is an `account number` and the second element is a `first name` but these are liable to change. E.g the company name `Test Corp` may not always exist in the data. This means I cannot use the numerical key `[3]` to target it because it may not be present.

Therefore I need to code this data into something that I can assign both a label for the data, and the data value. I'm guessing the best way to do this would be with an JSON object.

How can I create a key->value pair object? I would need to replace my `.push()` code above to instead add the value of `COMPANY NAME -> Test Corp` so that it can be deciphered later.

For reference, I am then stringifying this data and using an AJAX request to POST it to a PHP script where it will need to be arranged into variables e.g `$company_name = 'Test Corp';`

Comment: try this `values["account_number"] = "123456789";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about a plain JavaScript object. JSON is a transfer format inspired by JavaScript syntax.

To make an object, just initialize a variable:

```
var values = {};
```

And add properties:

```
values.accountNumber = "123456789";
values.firstName = "Joe";
```

etc. If you know the properties up front and have values available, you can make the object in one step:

```
var values = {
  accountNumber: "12345678",
  firstName: "Joe",
  // ...
};
```